# Relation between rank, nullity and orthogonal complement

Tags: orthogonality, matrix-rank

**Question**

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}_{d\times d}$  be some square, non-invertible matrix. 
Prove that if $b\perp\ker(A^T)$, then the non-homogenous system $Ax=b$ has $\infty$ solutions.

**Background**

I got this as an "$\iff$" question in my Intro to Machine Learning course in university.
I was able to prove the other direction, but no luck on this one.
I have previously proved these two lemmas:

1. $Im(A)=\ker(A^T)^\perp$,
2. $\ker(A^T)=\ker(AA^T)$.

**What I've tried**

I got here, but didn't know how to get to continue or if I even should.

$b\perp\ker\left(A^{T}\right)\iff b\perp\ker\left(AA^{T}\right)\\\iff b\perp\ker\left(\left(A^{T}A\right)^{T}\right)\\\iff b\in\ker\left(\left(A^{T}A\right)^{T}\right)^{\perp}\\\iff b\in im\left(A^{T}A\right)$

Any help appreciated, thank!

-Alon

Comment: $b \in Im(a)$ is equal to $Ax = b$ having a solution, so lemma 1 is all you need.

Comment: Oh, silly me, I switched the directions (what you said is what I've already proved).
::facepalm::
Thanks, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to bring in $AA^\top$ here. What's relevant is this: Since $A$ is *non-invertible*, if $Ax=b$ is consistent, it will have infinitely many solutions. Namely: To any particular solution $x_0$ you add any vector $u\in \ker(A)$, and then $A(x_0+u)=A(x_0)+A(u)=b$. Since $\ker(A)$ is at least one-dimensional, there are your infinitely many solutions. But your statement #1 tells you precisely that $b\in\text{Im}(A)$, so the equation $Ax=b$ *is* consistent (i.e., has at least one solution).